# Handling Azure Redis Cache exceptions

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm using Azure Redis Cache for development and wanted to verify the way I'm handling the exceptions. According to the best practices, it's possible to face RedisConnectionExceptions and to resolve this, we have to dispose the old ConnectionMultiplexer and create a new one. If abortConnect is set to false, then the multiplexer will silently retry connecting without throwing the error. So if the exception is thrown, it will only be after some attempts to reconect and still failing. Is my understanding of this correct?
This is my connection string -

```
cachename.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=Password,ssl=True,abortConnect=False
```

I believe the connection exception will only occus when you try to call GetConnection() on the multiplexer. Find my Code below -

```cs
    static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> multiplexer = CreateMultiplexer();

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer GetConnection() => multiplexer.Value;

    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> CreateMultiplexer()
    {
        return new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString));
    }

    private static void CloseMultiplexer(Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> oldMultiplexer)
    {
        if (oldMultiplexer != null)
        {
            oldMultiplexer.Value.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void Reconnect()
    {
        var oldMultiplexer = multiplexer;
        CloseMultiplexer(multiplexer);
        multiplexer = CreateMultiplexer();
    }
```

And I'm Consuming this below in another class -

```cs
    public class RedisCacheManager
    {
        private static IDatabase _cache;

        private TimeSpan expiry = new TimeSpan(hours: 6, minutes: 0, seconds: 0);

        public RedisCacheManager()
        {
            try
            {
                _cache = RedisCacheHelper.GetConnection().GetDatabase();
            }
            catch(RedisConnectionException)
            {
                RedisCacheHelper.Reconnect();
                new RedisCacheManager();
            }
        }

        public async Task<RedisValue[]> GetFromCacheAsync(List<string> keys)
        {
            var cacheValues = await _cache.StringGetAsync(keys.Select(k => (RedisKey)k).ToArray());
            return cacheValues;
        }

        public async Task SaveInCacheAsync<TValue>(Dictionary<string, TValue> kvps)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            foreach(var kvp in kvps)
            {
                tasks.Add(_cache.StringSetAsync(kvp.Key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kvp), expiry));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
        }
```

I'm not sure id calling the constructor in the catch block is a good practice. And are there any other exceptions that I would need to handle while calling StringGetAsync and StringSetAsync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CacheManager can look like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public sealed class RedisCacheManager : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _expiry;

    private readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> _lazyConnection;

    private ConnectionMultiplexer Connection { get => _lazyConnection.Value; }

    public RedisCacheManager(string connectionString, TimeSpan expiry)
    {
        _expiry = expiry;

        _lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString));
    }

    public async Task<RedisValue[]> GetFromCacheAsync(IEnumerable<string> keys)
    {
        var cacheValues = await Connection.GetDatabase()
          .StringGetAsync(keys.Select(key => (RedisKey)key).ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return cacheValues;
    }

    public async Task SaveInCacheAsync<TValue>(Dictionary<string, TValue> kvps)
    {
        var tasks = kvps
            .Select(kvp => Connection.GetDatabase().StringSetAsync(kvp.Key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(kvp), _expiry))
            .ToArray();

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_lazyConnection.IsValueCreated)
        {
            _lazyConnection.Value.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Using:

```
public readonly static RedisCacheManager RedisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager("connection string", TimeSpan.FromHours(6));
```

Remarks:

- it is intended that *abortConnect=false* (which means that the call succeeds even if a connection to the Azure Cache for Redis is not established) and from constructor shouldn't be thrown any Redis-exceptions
- The object returned from GetDatabase is a [cheap pass-thru object](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics.html#using-a-redis-database), and does not need to be stored.
- *GetFromCacheAsync* / *SaveInCacheAsync*-methods can throw an exception to outside and it is OK. You can apply [Retry-policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry) to resolve transient faults.
- If you have any IoC-container then it should create *RedisCacheManager* with a single instance scope (for example, [Autofac registration](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you see any drawback of storing the object returned from GetDatabase during initialization? If we are using a single instance of the manager, even if we store the databse value it would be reused, correct?